# How to pass a variable right through the routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I get an error when I try passing the var in the routes like this

```
<a  href="{{route('canvas',['size'=>1000])}}">
...
</a>
```

I pass the view like this

```
    public function canvas($size){
        return view('main.canvas')->with($size);
    }
```

this is the route I use in web.php:

```
Route::get('canvas',[CustomAuthController::class,'canvas'])->name('canvas');
```

the error I get is this:
Too few arguments to ...\CustomAuthController::canvas(), 0 passed in ...\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected

It seems the argument isn't being read for some reason,I tried just route('canvas',1000) but still not working

Comment: Can you show us the route that you use in the routes file ?

Comment: Yes sorry,forgot to add it

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `with()` with accessor.

> **Syntax:**  `->with('variable-name', $data)`

---

Your route should be.(You should allow property in URL)

```
Route::get('canvas/{size}', 'CustomAuthController@canvas');
```

And in controller

```
public function canvas($size){
    return view('main.canvas')->with('size',$size);
}
```

In blade you can

```
{{ $size }}
```

Comment: Thanks! In the routes I just added the /{size} and I changed the with() and it worked